# Run queries on different databases in EasyDB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement EasyDB into our current system, and having trouble running a query on a different database than the one I specified in my initial connection. I want to create query like this one:

```
INSERT INTO
leads.question_answers
SET
question_id = ?,
answer_id = ?
```

Using that `leads.question_answers` identifier will obviously let me run that query on the "leads" database instead of the "default" one I set in my connection.

With EasyDB I'm trying to run an insert(), looking like this:

```
$this->conn->insert('leads.question_answers', [
  'question_id' => $_REQUEST['question_id'],
  'answer_id' => $_REQUEST['answer_id']
]);
```

But it gives me the error "Separators (.) are not permitted." The EasyDB docs don't mention anything about being able to specify which database to run the query on, and nothing I've tried has worked. This will definitely be a problem since I have 5-6 different databases with different tables that will need to be queried in our setup.

Is there an easy way to do this with EasyDB, or should I drop that and just use mysqli on its own instead?

Comment: Definitely, never go back to mysqli. Even if you don't like EasyDB for some reason, you can still go back to PDO, which is 10 times better than mysqli.

Comment: My guess is I'm going to get frustrated with EasyDB more than once as I learn it, but I've read so many good things about it, I'll probably stick with it since it seems like it'll make my life easier in the long run. Thanks for the advice, good to know about sticking with PDO either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow the separators.

```
$this->conn->setAllowSeparators(true);
```